# Множественное подключение GMap API

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-maps-api

Есть ли возможность у GMaps API одновременно использовать 2 API keys одновременно на сайте? У меня есть определенная проблема в совместимости плагина и темы под WP. У каждого есть возможность вставить API key при этом возникает конфликт. Если отключить подключение скриптов GMap то в плагине все работает прекрастно. Но не работают карты если их добавлять не из плагина а из темы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите им одинаковый ключ, все будет работать.